# combining absolute and relative coordinates for axis label

Tags: pgfplots, positioning, labels

Consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.12,
    stdaxis/.style={
        ylabel style={at={(ticklabel cs:1.06)},anchor=west,rotate=270},
        }
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[stdaxis,ylabel=$f(x)$,xlabel=$x$]
    \addplot {x^2};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: produced output]

This is exactly what I want. My problem is that when I use the same `stdaxis` style for another picture with a different height, the y-axis label "f(x)" gets too high or too low. To circumvent this, I would like to use an absolute positioning and change the style to something like `ylabel style={at={(ticklabel cs:1.0+5mm)},anchor=west,rotate=270}`

How is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this with coordinate calculations using the TikZ library `calc` (cf. [section 13.5 of the PGF/TikZ manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf#subsection.13.5)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.12,
    stdaxis/.style={
        ylabel style={at={($(ticklabel cs:1.0)+(0mm,5mm)$)},anchor=west,rotate=270},
        }
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[stdaxis,ylabel=$f(x)$,xlabel=$x$]
    \addplot {x^2};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: example plot, with y label 5mm above the upper left corner of the axis box]

Comment: I almost tried this, but my mistake was that I assumed, the second coordinate should be one-dimensional, too (as is the axis coordinate). Thanks!
Note: [esdd's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/301049/78282) produces exactly the same output

Answer (score 4):

Use `yshift=5mm` *after* `rotate=270`:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.12,
    stdaxis/.style={
            ylabel style={at={(ticklabel cs:1)},
            anchor=west,
            rotate=270,
            yshift=5mm% <-
            },
        }
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[stdaxis,ylabel=$f(x)$,xlabel=$x$]
    \addplot {x^2};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[stdaxis,height=10cm,ylabel=$f(x)$,xlabel=$x$]
    \addplot {x^2};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for clarifying the yshift position! So far I didn't the logic behind this yet, I tried similar things but not after the rotate. As [diabonas' anser](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/301048/78282) was a bit faster and seems better understandable to me, I accepted that one, although yours produces exactly the same result and does not even need a further library loaded